# PostGIS - raster and bands

Tags: postgis, raster, postgresql, postgis-2.0

I have several images from different times and for every time I have three types of image (temperatureA, temperatureB, pressure). Should I store them as

- every time as band in a single raster with N bands => I will have (3) rows (one for every data type)
- every time as a single raster with 1 band => I will have (times count * 3) rows (one for every data type and for every time)
- all 3 types in bands of a single raster => I will have (times count) rows (one row for every time)

What is tbe best option?

I will mostly read from the database and update all data hourly. Users will be reading from PHP website values at [x, y] from a single time, but all three variables.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have created tests to see what is faster:

```
Selecting data from (1) band in (N) band raster - 240 ms
Selecting data from (1) band in (1) band raster - 70 ms
```

(Full results: [PostGIS raster and bands tests](http://www.perry.cz/clanky/postgis.html))

Answer (score 2):

I would create three tables and add a time column for every raster. Then your queries always have a "WHERE time = x" or "WHERE time < y".

Comment: Especially if you are going to be doing updates frequently, you want your rows to be as small in size as possible.  So more rows, but smaller size rows.